# SQL Query for data with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, fraud-prevention

I'm trying to find a way to create a query that returns transactions from individuals when they submit transactions that are traditionally accompanied by other transactions.

**Example (with data below):**

We see employees had a flight purchased (with the date the flight was purchased). Then they submitted baggage fees with transaction dates that match either the departure date and the return date. We then see they submitted a third one that doesn't match any of the airline dates.

Is there a way to identify for each person that has a baggage fee if they have an airline departure/return date that matches the transaction date? In the example below, the last baggage fees for each employee are the rows I'm hoping to return since they don't match the depart/return date for their respective flights.

**DB NAME = ExpenseTable**

| Employee | Type | TransactionDate | Depart | Return |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Airline | 12052019 | 12082019 | 12132019 |
| 123 | Baggage | 12082019 | NULL | NULL |
| 123 | Baggage | 12132019 | NULL | NULL |
| 123 | Baggage | 12252019 | NULL | NULL |
| 567 | Airline | 11052020 | 11082020 | 11132020 |
| 567 | Baggage | 11082020 | NULL | NULL |
| 567 | Baggage | 11132020 | NULL | NULL |
| 567 | Baggage | 11252020 | NULL | NULL |

Comment: Please explain what a "fraudulent transaction" is -- or remove that from the question.  Also, SQL doesn't highlight rows.  A query simply returns rows.  What result set do you want?

Comment: Please, don't yell in the title. It's extremely annoying.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks, updated the question.

Comment: @tadman apologies and good point. Rookie mistake on my part. I updated the prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use "WHERE NOT EXISTS" to do what you're looking for. Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Transactions T1
WHERE T1.Type = 'Baggage'
AND NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT *
    FROM Transactions T2
    WHERE T2.Type = 'Airline'
        AND (T1.TransactionDate = T2.Depart OR T1.TransationDate = T2.Arrive)
    )
```

The NOT EXISTS excludes any baggage records that have a matching airline record, based on either the depart date or arrive date. (Putting EXISTS by itself would do the opposite...it would only show baggage transactions with matching airline transactions.) You could probably do this with a join, but EXISTS/NOT EXISTS is nice because it doesn't give you duplicate rows in your result set.

Comment: I tried the code suggested but it did not return any values. When you write
"FROM Trasnactions T1 WHERE T1.Type = 'Baggage' " what is this doing? I assume its creating a table with just the baggage rows? Then we are trying to take the transaction date and match against airline depart/return dates in the subquery, returning rows that don't match? I typed in mine FROM [insert database name] Where Type = baggage. My assumption is that my version is missing a step?

Comment: That's my guess at what your tables are called. I don't actually know that you have a tabled called "Transactions".

Comment: worked! thanks a ton for helping! I had to modify the way I was naming my table. Really appreciate your assistance @Jim